# Как сохранить фрагменты в памяти?

Tags: java, android

Я использую MVP + Moxy+ BottomNavigation.

Моя задача состоит в том чтобы сохранять фрагменты в памяти. Сделать работу на подобии ViewPagerApdater.

Вообщем. У меня есть 3 фрагмента, они все наследуются от MVPFragment. Изначально ни один из фрагментов не создан. Я должен создать по нажатии на кнопку, тот или иной фрагмент 1 раз. Пока жив MainActivity.

Тоесть получается.

> Нажимаем на кнопку 1 создается 1 фрагмент.
>
> Нажимаем на кнопку 3 создается 3 фрагмент.
>
> Нажимаем на кнопку ничего не создалось заново, просто восстановился
>   фрагмент 1.
>
> Нажимаем на кнопку 2 создался 2 фрагмент.

и т.д.

Как такое реализовать в коде? Мучаюсь уже 4 день(((